# No boot in Devuan after installation - EFI Shell

Tags: linux, grub2, uefi, devuan, devuan-linux

I installed Devuan ASCII on a virtual machine on VirtualBox. Installation went smooth, but after installation I get the following EFI shell

[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb4FZ.png)

But any attempt to enter a BLK* device ended with the

```
current directory not specified
```

message [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t879x.png)

Here I add the Virtual Machine configuration [I used for the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlJct.png)

Comment: Looks like you have no ESP (EFI System Partition.)

Comment: So, if I am correct, I should create a boot partition, a ESP partition, a swap, a root partition and, eventually, a home partition.